# Dolphin starts with wrong shell when restored from last session

Tags: kde, plasma, konsole, dolphin

Dolphin has it's own embedded terminal (which is a KDE Konsole). My default shell is `zsh`. When Dolphin is restored from the last session (via KDE Plasma session management), it starts with `bash` instead of `zsh`. When I run `zsh` out of the running `bash`, Dolphin sometimes stops do synchronize the current folder in the GUI and the terminal. Restored Konsoles and newly opened Dolphin windows start properly with `zsh`.

How do I get restored Dolphin sessions to properly start with `zsh`?

I get this bug both on Kubuntu 20.04 with Plasma 5.18.5 and Arch with Plasma 5.20.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround, as mentioned here:

> The workaround is to choose a specific folder in the startup section of the dolphin settings. I hope that's useful for someone else.

Reddit: [Dolphin not running the default shell after update](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/icpqye/dolphin_not_running_the_default_shell_after_update/)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is to confirm your default shell is really your default shell.  Your default shell is stored in `/etc/passwd`

```
$ sudo grep $USER /etc/passwd
stew:x:1000:1000:Stewart,,,:/home/stew:/bin/bash
```

In my case, it is `bash`.  You can change this with:

```
$ sudo usermod --shell $(which zsh) $USER
```

Comment: Checked again and it is `/bin/zsh`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a known bug for a long time now

[Bug 425141 - Setting startup folder to "state from last time" makes .zshrc not load](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=425141)

[Bug 407990 - Dolphin terminal panel doesn't source .zshrc on session restore](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=407990)

Comment: Thank you, looks like you got it! Seems like nothing can be done about it of one wants to keep the session settings.