# kde dolphin terminal is not loading ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile

Tags: bash, dolphin

Since upgrading my debian. Bash in dolphin's terminal is not loading the config files. However, bash in Konsole is loading these.

What can I do to get Dolphin's terminal to load these?

After some testing I note that if I start dolphin with the shell closed and then open it, then all is good (it loads the configs). However, if dolphin starts with the shell open, it does not load the configs.

## `$-`

```
#↳ echo $-
himBHs
```

In both shells

## ~/.bash_profile

```
ll ~/.bash_profile
ls: cannot access '/home/richard/.bash_profile': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does dolphin have a setting to launch your shell as a login shell?

Comment: @glennjackman I can not find any login shell setting. I have added a section to my question.

Comment: A possible solution (but it's not so useful in my case) is:
Go to `Settings` -> `Startup` -> `Show on startup` and you select the second option to specify a location. That works but I prefer to save the windows state from the last time.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon can you tell us why that works. What is your reasoning. I tried it and it seems to work, but …

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm not really sure. I've had the same problem for a long time and I found that solution in reddit or another forum, I don't remember well. It seems that's a dolphin bug.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon can you put that workaround in an answer. If you label it workaround, then and nothing better comes along, then I will mark as accepted. Else at least an up vote.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor sure! I'll do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution should be useful for some people, in my case I really like the dolphin feature about  **Show on Startup** *Folders, tabs, and window state from last time*. If someone like that feature too then this solution will not be useful.

First, in dolphin you have to go to `Settings` -> `Configure dolphin`:

[image]

Now you have to choose `Startup` option and select the second option to specify a location:

[image]

That seems to work for everyone who has the same problem. However I've seen that's a dolphin bug though I remember reading that only in some distros this bug is present.

My current dolphin version: `22.08.1` and OS: `openSUSE Tumbleweed`

Comment: This does not help me in Opensuse 15.4. Also it is interesting that here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633675/dolphin-starts-with-wrong-shell-when-restored-from-last-session the workaround is to do the opposite.

Comment: Wow, and indeed, after changing the start directory to /home/username the problem is fixed. Perhaps the workaround is just do do some change. Not this specific one.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава thanks for pointing that out, it will be useful for some other users. I'm not sure but I remember this issue is solved in openSUSE tumbleweed (that's the distro I use and currently it seems to be working correctly now)